# What's the easiest way to remove the hand from this object?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I would like to remove the hand from the spear:

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots how do I do that?

Comment: Enter edit mode, select a part of the pole, press Ctrl+L to select the rest of the pole, press H to hide the pole, select all of the hand, press X to delete the hand. (Hide the pole first just to make selecting the hand easier if it's in separate pieces of geometry)

Comment: Read the instructions on the page at the link that @moonboots gave you.

Comment: @NascentSpace Granted that the hand is a separate piece, this would work - but why so complicated? Hover your mouse over the hand, press L and then X to delete the hand. Unfortunately the hand is connected to the pole.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I assumed that the pole was its own separate piece and was trying to account for the possibility of the hand being separated in some places, perhaps with fingernails or something and was trying to account for that. Didn't realize the hand was connected to the pole.

Answer (score 5):

In *Edit* mode, cut with the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through), then remove all the vertices inbetween:

[image]

Then select the top circle and the bottom circle, activate the *LoopTools* addon, and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *LoopTools > Bridge*:

[image]